# multi thread - ms test - data driven test

Tags: c#, multithreading, mstest, data-driven

**Background**

I have written a test suite in "mstest" which has a template XML.

The test populates this template with data from my database and posts it to a web service. When the web service replies with a response, input XML data is compared with the XML data received from the service in its response, and entries are logged in a text file.

Basically this test has one entry point function (it's the only function with the test method attribute) which then drives all the other functions in the test

**The problem**

The problem is that when the test takes too long. Posting to the web service and getting back a reply takes almost **2 mins** for each instance and I have 100 such data instances, so it would take about 200 mins at a minimum to complete.

My Boss told me to look into multi-threading this test thus hopefully reducing time.

One more thing i would like to point out is that I am going through different input xml instances using the DataSource attribute similar to what is mentioned in [this article](http://keithelder.net/2008/05/15/create-one-unit-test-with-a-bunch-of-data-driven/). The difference is that I am using a view from my DB to run the datasource attribute rather than a CSV file.

Any ideas how to multi thread this test and maintain thread safety will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So, your problem at a glance is: **web service takes 2 minutes to complete**. What kind of a service is this? Can you speed this part up?

Comment: its a QA server, and is used for every thing by the company therefore the work load on it is heavy, cant fix that.

Comment: The problem is, if the workload is that heavy, I don't think you can expect it to finish faster by sending all 100 queries at once. For example, if this is a db query for a database which has poorly configured indexes, each query will need a lot of cpu and disk time. Since these resources are limited, your queries will become 100 times longer.

Comment: @user602182 If I understand well your comment above, you run your tests in an Env that is used by all people work in your company. This is not a good option at all. You need to set up a QA Env where only your team will have access to execute their tests. You may need to set up different Environments for each project you test. This will keep your Testing unaffected. If you don't do that, I'm afraid you cannot solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TPL works for me, just had to ensure each and every variable was local

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate on how you execute the calls to "mstest"?
If you are manually executing test execution, then you can add multi-thread support very easily and save a lot of precious time, as your boss has in mind :)

I attached this MSDN overview link which also covers the basics for thread safety:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178.aspx

If you're using a built-in option of the IDE/test application, that you may be limited to the functionality it has to offer.

Waiting for your answer.

Comment: sorry i don't quite understand "how you execute the calls to "mstest"? " what you mean by this?